# angular/flex-layout beta8 gets TypeError: _this._renderer.setStyle is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

Code was working fine on @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.7

Just upgraded to @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.8
got this error.

```
TypeError: _this._renderer.setStyle is not a function
```

If I ignore it, then console throws a second error saying

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
```

version of other modules:

- @angular/core@4.0.3
- @angular/materail@2.0.0-beta.2

What's wrong? How should I tackle the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug with angular's DI, rather than this module specifically. I'd recommend making a minimal plunker that reproduces your issue and posting it on the angular issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

bug fixed in @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.8 via pull request #298
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/pull/298